# Представление кучи и стека

Tags: память, стек

Как физически выглядят куча и стек в оперативной памяти?

Comment: так а доступ в куче проходит медленнее чем в стэке. Или это присходит на программном а не аппаратном уровне?

Comment: @voipp: чё? Мы говорим о сериализации или о виртуальной памяти? «Доступ **в** куче происходит медленнее» — эта информация откуда?

Comment: какая куча? какой стек на жестком диске?

Comment: Может автор изучает вопрос виртуальной памяти - да, куча и стек могут оказаться на жестком диске, если их туда засвоппит операционная система. Другой вопрос, что стек в данном случае это некий сегмент (область памяти) программы, а куча будет в сегмента данных (с атрибутами RW), в противовес сегменту кода (который RO). А вообще странно говорить про такие вещи - нужно отделять мух от котлет и теплое не мешать с мягким.

Comment: >Может автор изучает вопрос виртуальной памяти

тогда пусть уточнит, что именно его интересует

Comment: нет,я  про оперативную память!!

Comment: "Физически" это транзисторы и конденсаторы

Comment: не, я хочу понять, кто разделил память на быстрый стэк и медленную кучу? это сделано на аппаратном уровне? или программном?

Comment: @voipp, а почему Вы решили, что стек *быстрый*, а куча *медленная*?

Насколько мне известно, время доступа к памяти в них **одинаковое**.

Comment: ну , я читал, что стек меньше хипа, в нем хранятся данные, которыми вы пользуетесь чаще и поэтому доступ должен быть быстрее. Самый быстрый - это положить в регистры, но в джаве такого окажется нет

Comment: @voipp: Мне не кажется, что информация, которую вы прочитали, соответствует действительности. Как правильно сказал @DreamChild, и стек, и хип — не более чем аппаратура. То, что стек меньше хипа по размеру в типичном случае, не значит ничего: вы можете обращаться к данным локально в хипе и нелокально в стеке. (Вы имели в виду кэширование на уровне процессора, но оно работает не так, как вы думаете.) Регистров в языках высокого уровня нет и не будет никогда по многим причинам (например, потому, что оптимизирующий компилятор умеет оптимизировать лучше человека.)

Comment: Почитал комментарии к вопросу и так и не понял, вопрос про Cache vs Mem, или про выделение памяти Heap vs Stack.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. И стек и куча оба находятся физически в RAM (не рассматриваем архитектурные вывихи с использованием спец. процессоров/компов)
2. Их размеры и расположение определяются осью
3. При этом куча может быть фрагментирована (иногда довольно сильно). Обычно у осей бывают специальные процедуры для дефрагментации кучи.
4. Стек обычно никогда не фрагментирован (наверное можно придумать реализации стека с фрагментацией, но это оксюморон).
5. Стек как бы быстрее потому, что у него единственный параметр с которым работает - это указатель положения стека (обычно регистр) - поэтому все операции со стеком работают в разы быстрее чем с кучей. Операция извлечения/записи из стека это 1 телодвижение процессора `POP/PUSH`
6. С кучей сложнее именно из-за его фрагментации и простая операция извлечения значения из него может вылиться в десятки (если не сотни) телодвижений процессора.
7. Минусы стека в малости его размера (он всегда по сравнению с кучей на порядок меньше) - ну и в том, что доступ к нему только последовательный.

Comment: @Barmaley:

6) Это имеет смысл для выделения памяти в куче, но если у вас есть указатель на объект в куче, и указатель на объект в стеке, скорость доступа строго одинакова.

7) Опять-таки, доступ ведётся не последовательным чтением, а разыменованием указателя.

Comment: Действительно, скорость доступа к данным в стеке и куче одинакова. 

Т.е. **пункты 5) и 6) это ошибка.** 

Я не поленился и проверил время заполнения (несколько попыток) массива из 2 млн. int (больше в стек у меня не влезает) в куче и стеке.

    void fill (int a[], int n) {
      srand(0);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[rand() % n] = rand();
    }

Такой метод избран, чтобы минимизировать влияние кэша и предвыборки данных в него.

Результаты (clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &ts);)

    ./a.out 100
    stack:  avg:     43.332 (msec)
    heap:  avg:     42.283 (msec)

Comment: @avp надо не так пробовать, надо добиться того, чтобы куча фрагментировалась - с этой целью надо сделать тучу рандомных аллокаций разного размера и также хаотично их удалять, только после этого проверьте скорость доступа к большому (!) массиву в куче. А иначе если куча не фрагментирована скорость конечно будет одинаковой.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, в любом случае весь массив в куче будет находиться в последовательных ячейках (естественно, в виртуальном адресном пространстве).

Или Вы рассматриваете теоретчески возможню в cc-NUMA ситуацию, когда ОС выделяет процессу память (mmap-ом?) из физической памяти другого узла?

--

К сожалению, во первых, сейчас у меня нет доступа к подобной системе, ну, а во вторых, я не очень представляю, как смоделировать в cc-NUMA такую *устойчиво повторяемую* ситуацию.

Comment: @avp именно так - конечно в виртуальном адресном пространстве память будет в последовательных ячейках, но в реальном исполнении она будет фрагментирована - именно из-за фрагментации и упадет скорость доступа.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, а физическая память всегда может быть фрагментирована, что в куче, что в стеке, что в коде.

Но тут Вы заблуждаетесь, на скорость доступа (в обычных, а не NUMA архитектурах) это не влияет.

Answer (score 25):

Хоть и прошло много времени с тех пор как вы задали вопрос, хотелось бы ответить, ведь все равно данный вопрос "гуглится" и, я думаю, что многие ещё посетят эту страницу.

Как вам уже ответили "физически" - это транзисторы и конденсаторы.
Так что сам вопрос скорее всего был поставлен не совсем корректно. 
Наверное, вы имели в виду что-то вроде - "Где находится куча и стек, как они устроены".

Также , наверное , вас интересует как в целом устроена память, полностью осветить этот вопрос у меня не выйдет, но я хочу вам показать, исчерпывающий на мой взгляд, материал и дать ссылки на них. Материалы на русском. 
Вам нужно разобраться, что такое **виртуальное память** и как она транслируется в физическую.

Вот пример организации сегментной памяти.

[image: изображение взято из статьи http://jpauli.github.io/2015/04/16/segmentation-fault.html]

Суть в том, что адресное представление в "виртуальной памяти" отличается от физической. Но для процесса(программы) это не важно, т.к. распределением памяти(выделением/освобождением) для занимается не она. Этим занимаются различные механизмы ОС и [MMU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)

Для более глубинного понимания, вам нужно ознакомиться с понятием "виртуальная память", а также со способами её организации "Сегментная адресация памяти","Страничная память"

Это кратко и немного по поводу представления виртуальной памяти в физическую.

По поводу устройства памяти внутри процесса:

[image: внутри процесса]

Снова вкратце, процесс думает, что ему выделяется цельное пространство, в котором уже размещаются области - "код","стек", "куча".
Стек заполняется и растет при вызове новых методов в свободную область в сторону УМЕНЬШЕНИЯ адресов. Куча растет наоборот в сторону УВЕЛИЧЕНИЯ адресов. За тем, чтобы памяти хватило снова-таки следит ОС.

Что хранится в блоке CODE, а также о много другом вы можете узнать из рекоммендованных мной материалов в этой ответе.

Рекоммендую читать в расположенном мной порядке, предложенные мной статьи к ознакомлению.

1. [Азы устройства памяти](https://habrahabr.ru/company/nixsolutions/blog/277759/)
2. Известная статья ["Что каждый программист должен знать о памяти"](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/hard/memory/memory.html)
3. [Организация виртуальной памяти. Таблицы страниц и прочее.](https://habrahabr.ru/company/embox/blog/256191/)
4. [Преобразование логического адреса в линейный.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/128991/)
5. [Устройство MMU](https://habrahabr.ru/post/211150/)
6. Элемент списка

Мне  не совсем понятны "рейтинговые ответы" на ваш вопрос, поскольку люди в них ушли, на мой некомпетентный взгляд, в обсуждение других тем.

Answer (score 6):

Лучше сказать так. Типичными операциями при работе с памятью являются её выделение/освобождение и чтение/запись. Операции выделения и освобождения памяти работают в куче медленнее.

Доступ к данным (чтение/запись) происходит практически с одинаковой скоростью. Практически - потому что в стеке типичным является доступ к значениям напрямую, а в куче - через указатель. Напрямую на самом деле тоже означает что-нибудь в духе ptr [esp+10h], т.е. чтобы получить данные, процессору нужно прибавить некоторое число к значению регистра esp и обратиться к памяти по этому адресу. Если (типичная ситуация) указатель на фрагмент памяти в куче лежит на стеке, то возникает два уровня косвенности - сначала надо получить значение указателя через "ptr [esp+10h]", а потом прочитать значение по этому адресу.

Если же мы, например, заводим указатель на данные, лежащие в стеке, то разницы в скорости доступа не будет абсолютно никакой.

Comment: "Доступ к данным (чтение/запись) происходит практически с одинаковой скоростью"  А если данные фрагментированы, то разве чтение их не замедлится?

Comment: @voipp: Что означает «данные фрагментированы»? Если вы говорите о фрагментировании массива, то такого не бывает, массив всегда идёт подряд. Если у вы говорите об обращении к разным объектам, они могут быть разнесены в памяти и при их расположении в стеке, и в куче.

Comment: Да, поддерживаю @VladD. Структура тоже не может быть фрагментирована. Если у вас на стеке структура с std::string, то содержимое строки, обычно, - уже в куче :) . Скорее надо задумываться о структурах данных, которые стоит использовать, а не об их расположении. Список, допустим, иногда может быть лучше массива, но он предрасположен к фрагментации (и больше памяти расходует)...