# Скорость обращения к локальным и глобальным переменным

Tags: java

Заинтересовала разница в скорости обращения к глобальным и локальным переменным(в других темах ответ не был найден). Есть 2 переменные - long set глобальная и long set локальная. При 10 млрд изменений глобальной переменной, время работы составляло 3.600 сек. При тех же 10 млрд, но с локальной переменной время стало на 400 мсек меньше(3.200 сек). В чем причина такой огромной разницы? Понимаю, что замеры сделаны, грубо говоря, "на коленке", но все же, причина в чем-то кроется.

```
package other;

public class w {
static long time;
long set = 0; //static or not = 3600 ms
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new w().test();
}
public void test(){
    long set = 0; // 3200 ms
    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " become work!");
    time = System.nanoTime();
    for(long a = 0; a < 10000000000L; a++)
        set = a;
    time = (System.nanoTime() - time);
    System.out.println("End of " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with "+ time/1000000.0 + "millisec");
}
}
```

Comment: вообще забавно. jdk 1.8.0_92 в вашем тесте просто ничего не присваивает локальной переменной, т.к. она не возвращается (почему не выкидывается весь цикл - другой вопрос). А вот если сделать `return set` в конце метода, то ситуация меняется и тест с локальной переменной тормозит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница проявляется из-за разницы в месте хранения.

Глобальные и статические переменные помещаются в [сегмент данных](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

Локальные (автоматические) переменные помещаются [в стек](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Stack)

При прочих равных условиях, обычно - обращение к стеку работает быстрее обращения к сегменту данных.

Однако, сейчас с виртуализацией адресных пространств и проч. фишками все очень зыбко, непредсказуемо и зависит от конкретной реализации.

Вообще, споры о том что быстрее: куча, сегмент данных или стек - это любимая тема срача/холивара в разных форумах. ruSO не исключение - здесь тоже это многократно происходило, [например здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/277295/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0/277853#277853)

Comment: спасибо! Почитаю про стек/сегмент данных

Comment: По-моему, здесь определяющую роль играет уровень косвенности. Локальная переменная сама лежит в стеке, а доступ к полю объекта осуществляется через ссылку на объект, которая лежит в стеке. В первом случае, условно говоря, `a = [sp + x]`, во втором - `a = [[sp + x] + y]`, на одно обращение к памяти больше.