# Зачем выделять память для переменных в стеке?

Tags: c++, стек

*В теме еще разбираюсь плохо так что прошу строго не судить.*

Насколько я понял, стек в основном нужен для правильного последовательного распределения выполнения функций в программе. Его вместимость ограничена и он может быть переполнен тем самым вызвав ошибку. Ввиду этого у меня возник вопрос: Почему бы чтобы уменьшить заполненность стека по дефолту не кидать все переменные в кучу?

Сам предполагаю что это вызвано тем, что процесс резервирования и освобождения памяти на стеке происходит быстрее чем в куче и по этому было бы рациональнее хранить небольшие данные в нем. Правильно ли я понимаю или нет?

Comment: Да, вы правильно понимаете. Резервирование памяти в стеке заключается в перемещении указателя вершины, что происходит мгновенно. А поддержка кучи - это сложный механизм который гораздо медленнее. Хотя у стека еще одно преимущество, каждый запуск рекурсивной функции (которая вызывает сама себя) получает отдельный кусок стека, поэтому все локальные переменные как раз локальные, только для текущего выполнения. С кучей такой фокус не пройдет, как минимум вам надо будет где то сохранить указатель на выделенную память так, что бы он был локальным

Comment: И да, на многих процессорах, включая платформу intel, стек поддерживается на уровне процессора.А куча - чисто програмная реализация

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/277295/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вы имеете в виду под "кидать все переменные в кучу". Никто вам не запрещает этого делать (в том числе самостоятельно), но тем не менее динамическое расписание выделения/освобождения такой памяти все равно будет стековым: последний выделился - первый освободился. Как ни верти, это все равно будет лишь альтернативной реализацией стека. Или вы о чем-то другом говорите?

Answer (score 1):

Локальные переменные размещаются в стеке, чтобы быть локальными не только для функции, но и для каждой итерации ее вызова.
Когда функция запускает сама себя рекурсивно, она должна получить новый блок памяти под локальные переменные, а при возврате первая должна обратно вернуть свои. И единственное что с точки зрения процессора отличает эти два "экземпляра" функции - указатель базы стека.

Если у вас локальные переменные суммарно хранят большой объем данных (от сотни килобайт и выше), то имеет смысл выделять область в куче, и хранить указатель на нее в стеке.

Почему такой механизм не применяется по умолчанию - потому что это медленнее и в 99% случаев не нужно.